# How to increase branch coverage in junit test case for for loop with if condition?

Tags: javascript, object

My test Javascript file "buildButtons.js"

```js
let viewButtonList = [
  { buttonLink: "about", buttonLabel: "ABOUT" },
  { buttonLink: "contact", buttonLabel: "CONTACT" },
  { buttonLink: "prodcucts", buttonLabel: "PRODUCTS" },
  { buttonLink: "don't include", buttonLabel: "DON'T INCLUDE" }
]

let buttonList = []

let buildButtons = true

export function buildButtonList() {
  for (let item of viewButtonList) {
    if (buildButtons) {
      buttonList.push(item)
    }
  }
  return buttonList.filter(item => item.buttonLink !== "don't include")
}
```

And here is my junit test file for "buildButtons.js"

```js
import { buildButtonList } from "@/common/test.js"

let viewButtonList = [
  { buttonLabel: "ABOUT", buttonLink: "about" },
  { buttonLabel: "CONTACT", buttonLink: "contact" },
  { buttonLabel: "PRODUCTS", buttonLink: "prodcucts" },
  { buttonLabel: "DON'T INCLUDE", buttonLink: "don't include" }
]

let mockButtonList = [
  { buttonLabel: "ABOUT", buttonLink: "about" },
  { buttonLabel: "CONTACT", buttonLink: "contact" },
  { buttonLabel: "PRODUCTS", buttonLink: "prodcucts" }
]

let buttonList = []

let buildButtons = true

describe("Test buildButtonList function", () => {
  it("Should call the function 'buildButtonList'", () => {
    expect(buildButtonList()).toEqual(mockButtonList)
  })
})
```

And here is the output of code coverage of my test.

[test coverage result for buildButtons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CYm7.png)

Someone please suggest to get 100% code coverage while testing this code in junit test cases.
I've tried but couldn't able to cover the line where if condition inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean with "branch coverage" on "for loop", but you can set what percentage of the branch, functions and lines of code should be tested.

```
// .jestrc.json

"coverageThreshold": {
  "global": {
    "branches": 80,
    "functions": 80,
    "lines": 40,
    "statements": -20
  }
},
```

The above would force you to have 80% of branches covered, 80% of functions covered and 40% of lines covered.  If you're using a loop then I suggest putting it in a function so that jest picks up the coverage on the function itself.

Side note, I've found that setting it to 100% is not a good idea in most projects beacuse i.e. express router functions and socket.io server initialization can't really be tested in the way jest expects, so you will have some "uncovered" tests according to jest even if you have actually tested them.  100% will just frustrate you.